Help understanding NEC requirements for junction box access
Wiring my first big home project and understandably/expectedly failed my first inspection.
I've got 3 places in a circuit just for outlets where I used a J box to conserve on wire. I nailed the boxes 1.5" behind where the drywall would rest and put covers on them. It was only later I found out that the inspector wants these boxes accessible without cutting into the ceiling drywall.
The boxes are in really bad places for aesthetics. I really, really don't want them visible with an exposed cover plate in the ceiling.
Is the stated verbal requirement to move the boxes forward and make them accessible actually a requirement in the NEC?

N 314.29(A) In Buildings and Other Structures. Boxes and conduit bodies shall be installed so the contained wiring can be accessed without removing any part of the building or structure.

Maybe there are other references to this in the NEC, but in this one, it's unclear if cutting the drywall open would equate to "removing [any] part of the building".
If it is a requirement, I'm likely going to remove them entirely and rerun 100' of wire. Not looking forward to that at all.

Any chance of adding light fixtures to the J-boxes?  Could use pull string switch lights or smart bulbs.  Walls are much easier because you can use a picture or make an access door to hide J-boxes.  Lift a picture off or open a door is okay to hide them.

Please please please as someone whom was nearly killed by a hidden junction box, I implore you to not leave it this way.  Its more than just a code violation, its a real danger.

What about a slightly lower-profile access panel that could be installed more or less flush, then painted to match the rest of the ceiling?

What's on the other side of the wall?   Can you turn your boxes around and have them accessible through the other side of the wall ?   Can you add some built-in furniture here to mask the boxes but with a simple and obvious door to reveal them ?

Not unclear at all. Drywall is part of the building. If you have to cut it to get to the box, the box is hidden. Hidden boxes are bad.

The cutting of the drywall to access a buried junction box is not allowed by the electrical code. Think how it would be for someone other than you that would not be able to even know there were junction boxes hidden in the ceiling or wall.
If the space above this ceiling is accessible as an "attic" space them you may be able to mount the junction boxes on the top of the ceiling joists if you are easily able to work in that space.

Understood. Makes sense. Unfortunately this is a basement so above would mean cutting through century-old hardwoods and putting plates there. Sounds like I've got a lot more wire to run! Time to delete some boxes.

Could put a hardwired smoke alarm on that box.

That's a great idea @Brad!

@JeremyP.Beasley Remember code requires smoke alarms be interconnected, which is either wired or wireless, and that the smoke alarm cannot be located in certain locations, most restrictive for non-flat ceilings

@user71659: Last I checked, the interconnect on smoke detectors are not required on partial remodels because that would be too restrictive.

As someone who has just moved into a house wired with the approach of "save some cable with a JB" I'd say just don't, do it properly.  What I have here is completely incomprehensible, it took an electrician two days of moving furniture, lifting carpets and boards and scratching head to figure out why some sockets didn't work, happily paid for by the previous owners. I want to extend circuits but can't be sure they'll be safe or legal because I don't know how they're wired. House wiring had a potential lifetime of decades, the extra cable cost would have been trivial compared to the longer term consequences.
